# "SparkContext has been shutdown" when using df.select("Column Name") in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am creating a Spark Session on Scala that pulls a large amount of data from MongoDB into a DataFrame. Whenever I attempt to show only one column of that DataFrame I get the following error:

```
(run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown
```

I have tried reducing the size of my data to only 10 lines but still get the same error. The end goal is to sum all values in the "Rev" column and return as a variable, but need to overcome this issue first.

Here is snippet of my code, where `URI`

```
val sparkMongo = SparkSession.builder() // Creates a Spark instance that connects to MongoDB
      .appName("MongoSparkConnector")
      .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "8g")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", URI)
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", URI)
      .getOrCreate()
      import sparkMongo.implicits._

val df = sparkMongo.read // Creates Dataframe for scalanahw from Mongo
    .format("mongo")
    .option("url", URI)
    .option("collection", "collection_name")
    .option("take",10)
    .load()

val temp = df.select("Rev")

sparkMongo.stop()
```

The code compiles and runs fine without the `select` function (second to last line of code below). I have tried caching my dataframes, increasing driver and executor memory to 20g, and removing `sparkMongo.stop()` but it has produced the same error. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**EDIT SOLVED**
As is that case with a lot of programming errors, I had made a stupid mistake and had included `sparkMongo.stop()` before attempting to use `select` and hence the error stating that the SparkContext had been shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

`select` is a transformation that executes lazily; you will need some sort of terminal operation(`collect`, `count`, etc)

Since your 'temp' variable seems more about giving yourself some feedback as you make progress with your code, I might suggest the [show](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#show--) operation:

```
df.select("Rev").show()
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your input. Can you kindly elaborate or potentially provide an example please?